# Making Static Buttons

Tags: graphics, color, gui-construction, style, button

Is it possible to get a button that remains still when clicked? That is, it does not show the temporary pressed frames

[image]

This also happens when I set `Appearance -> "Frameless"`

[image]

as well as others. What I want is to be able to change the background colour of the button under the `"Frameless"` appearance without this pressed animation.

With `Appearance -> "Pressed"` there is no change, but the button remains pressed and I cannot change its background color. Instead it shows me the negative of that colour, so I could simply use `ColorNegate` to make it work. If want green, for example, I could do

```
Button["Hello", Appearance -> {"Frameless", "Pressed"}, 
 Background -> ColorNegate[Green]]
```

[image]

I'm wondering however, whether there is a better approach and how this translates into other operating systems (I'm using Windows 10). Could there be a difference in the way the pressed color is computed?

Comment: How about just not using a button? You could for example `EventHandler["Hello", {"MouseClicked" :> Beep[]}]`

Comment: how about `Button["", 
 Appearance -> {"Default" ->  Rasterize[Framed["Hello", RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> Red,  FrameStyle -> None]],    "Pressed" ->  Rasterize@
     Framed["Hello", RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> LightBlue, 
      FrameStyle -> Blue],   "Hover" ->  Rasterize@ Framed["Hello", RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> Orange,  FrameStyle -> None]}, ImageSize -> All]`?

Comment: ... or `Button[Panel["Hello",  Background -> Dynamic@If[CurrentValue[{"MouseButtonTest", 1}], Green, If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Orange, Red]]], Appearance -> None]`

Comment: `Button[Panel["Hello", Background -> Green, FrameMargins -> 0], 
 Appearance -> None]` or `Button["",  Appearance ->  Rasterize@Panel["Hello", Background -> Green, FrameMargins -> 0]]`?

Comment: slight modification of your approach: `Button["Hello", Appearance -> {"Pressed" -> None},  Background -> Green]`